# How long should a mortgage take to appear on my credit report?

Tags: mortgage, credit-report

I bought a house earlier this year (closed on 30 Jan 2015), and while the two inquiries (prequalification from one bank, then the 'actual' lender we went with) about my mortgage appear on my report (per Credit Karma & Credit Sesame (both in the first week of Jan 2015)), the mortgage has yet to appear (as of this question date - 23 Apr 2015).

When I have opened a new credit card, it has always appeared on my report within 1-2 billing cycles (never more than 60 days) of being opened.

Shouldn't my mortgage have appeared on my report by now?

How long should it take to show up?

Comment: mine appear in the first 60-90 days usually

Comment: Note that this differs by lender - it's up to them to report it - so you may want to ask yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it takes a month or two. Same holds true for when your loan servicing is sold.

Comment: so the fact it's already been sold twice (though only servicing once) may make it take longer?

Comment: possibly.  It sounds like you received a loan from a correspondent lender.  If that is the case your loan and servicing were sold immediately after funding; even though it may have taken a couple weeks for you to be notified.  If it takes more than two months to report, I would call them.